# Images working in Debug but not working in Microsoft Store - UWP Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store-apps, xamarin.uwp

I have created scale-100 folder in UWP project, added multiple images to it with Build Action set to Content and Copy to Output Directory set to Copy Always.

In code I use image name + extension and the images work while debugging locally.

However, when I create package and upload it to Microsoft Store, the application seems to work, but images are not loaded and are not visible.

Anyone could help me with this??

Comment: Which way you use image xaml or code-behind?

Comment: Could you test run the app within release mode with visual studio ?

Comment: I simply put image source="filename.png" and it works on Android iOS both debug and stores, for uwp it works in debug only. I will check in release now

Comment: I have tested release mode, it works well, you could try to generate a new package and upload again.

Comment: use embedded pictures or [ResizetizerNT](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT#how-to-use-it) to autoscale images

Comment: ok, I have managed to get images to work on store by copying them from scale-100 folder to UWP root folder. This way the paths are resolved in Microsoft Store.

Comment: Does image display when copy the image into uwp root folder?

Comment: with images in both locations it works. I will roll out next package without scale-100 folder to see if it works

Comment: Ok, please let me know the result thanks.

Comment: You could also use `ImageSource.FromFile` method to load image like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941316/7254781).

Comment: Do you have any updates for this topic?